# How to remove borders of a portlet added using <liferay:runtime ... /> tag

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to add a custom portlet in a JSP using  tag, here is the code:

```
<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="customSocialNotifications_WAR"  />
```

That works fine! But the portlet is showing the borders, and I need to hide them.

I tried to overwrite CSS, but then he removes all the borders of the portal :(

Some idea?

Thanks!

PD: I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE ;)

Comment: Can you try setting portlletSetupShowBorder to false using defaultPreferences attribute of liferay-portlet:runtime tag?

Comment: Works fine! Perfect with the Md Azaz Ali example below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a attribute available in same tag as defaultPreferences

```
<%
StringBundler sb = new StringBundler();
sb.append("<portlet-preferences >");
sb.append("<preference>");
sb.append("<name>");
sb.append("portletSetupShowBorders");
sb.append("</name>");
sb.append("<value>");
sb.append("false");
sb.append("</value>");
sb.append("</preference>");
sb.append("</portlet-preferences>");
%>


<liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="customSocialNotifications_WAR"  defaultPreferences="<%=sb.toString()%>"/>
```