# Saving preferences in a embedded portlet added with liferay-portlet:runtime tag

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created a portlet (parent) that shows as the content of accordion an embedded portlet (also created by me).

As context, below the JSP (view mode) of the parent portlet:

```html
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>

<jsp:useBean id="titulo" class="java.lang.String" scope="request" />


<portlet:defineObjects />

<%! String idPortlet="test_WAR_boxportlet_INSTANCE_fadewsio22a";  %>
<div class="root-accordion">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordion<%= idPortlet %>">
        <div class="accordion-group accordion-caret">  
            <div class="accordion-group accordion-caret">  
                <div class="accordion-heading accordion-cabecalho">
                    <a href="#conteudoac<%= idPortlet %>" data-parent="#accordion<%= idPortlet %>" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed">
                        <%= titulo %>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="conteudoac<%= idPortlet %>">
                    <div class="accordion-inner accordion-conteudo">

                        <liferay-portlet:runtime portletName="<%= idPortlet %>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent portlet has preferences (edit mode) as well as the embedded portlet.
But, when I try to save the preferences of the embedded portlet, the page reloads but doesn't manage to exit of the edit mode of the embedded portlet.
The setting of preferences works well for the portlet used as embedded when it used standalone (not embedded). The edit of "Preferences" in the parent portlet is OK in both scenarios.

Are there restrictions when the parent and the embedded portlet have both "Preferences" options?

What I must do for edit (save) preferences work in the embedded portlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the LPS explaining why such way isn't it possible at the moment and won't be fixed for current version https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-33767

However, the way I can suggest you is to define these preferences by part of code added to tag. I don't know if this will solve your scenario, still is the best idea I think at the moment. Here is some [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769758/how-to-remove-borders-of-a-portlet-added-using-liferayruntime-tag%20example) which isn't prettiest one but still.

Comment: As I mentioned to official statement given by Liferay Staff, you can't manage preferences for embedded portlets 'standart way' as standalone one. Maybe you should redesign your portlets. Is embedding portlet inside of another portlet only way to solve it? How about making dependency in scope compile for the parent portlet?